# Pandas: Casting a float column to int while also keeping the NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I have data like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'val1': [5.3, np.nan, 2.0, 1.2, 5]})
print(df)

   val1
0   5.3
1   NaN
2   2.0
3   1.2
4   5.0
```

I know that I can use [astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to convert the datatype of columns. The two possibiliteis I know for the target datatype are: `int` and `pd.Int64Dtype()` .

However, with `int` I have a problem with NaN values (I do want to keep the NaNs and not fill them with any other value):

```
df = df.astype({'val1': 'int'})

ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

Whereas with `pd.Int64Dtype()`, I have a problem with float values that would have to be cast to int:

```
df = df.astype({'val1':pd.Int64Dtype()})

TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64
```

How do I both cast my floats to ints and keep my NaNs?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do so, because `NaNs` are of type float, not int. You can for sure round the numbers to integers, but as long as there is a `NaN` in the column, it will remain `dtype = float`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: i misundesrtood the question,

```
def cast(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return None

df = df.apply(cast)
```

Comment: OP wants  NaNs, not 0s. Average, median or any operation will provide different values.

Comment: oh, I thought the question was something else, what about now? is it correct?